# SFML starting a new song once another song is complete

Tags: c++, sfml

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window/Event.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio/Music.hpp>


using namespace std;

int main (){

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My Window");

        sf::Music music;
        if (!music.openFromFile("Music/Fallen-Down.ogg"))
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    music.play();

//  if(!music.openFromFile("Music/CORE.ogg"))
//      return EXIT_FAILURE;

    while (window.isOpen()){
            // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration        of the loop
            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
             // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                         window.close();                
            }
        
        if(music.getStatus() == 0)
            music.play();
    
        window.clear(sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 0));

        window.display();

        }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have my basic window which opens and plays a song. All I want to do is play the next song "CORE.ogg" when the first song "Fallen-Down"is finished playing. I have tried using the `getStatus()` function from the [SFML Documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/annotated.php) which I believe returns an integer corresponding to the status of the song from an enum defined as

`enum Status {Stopped, Paused, Playing}`

I check which number it returns and if it returns `0` i was hoping it would play again. It's in the window loop so it should be checking at the end of every loop the status of the song...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the music to play again, then you need to `stop()` the current music, even though it has come to its own end, because that will rewind the music back to the beginning.

```
if(music.getStatus() == sf::SoundSource::Status::Stopped)
{
    music.stop(); // rewind to beginning
    music.play();
}
```

BTW you should use `sf::SoundSource::Status::Stopped` rather than `0` as it may change value in a future version or on another platform.

If you want to play different music, you need to load it:

```
if(music.getStatus() == sf::SoundSource::Status::Stopped)
{
    music.openFromFile("Music/CORE.ogg");
    music.play();
}
```

Comment: perfect. just a few of the small details had to be worked out! thanks so much. I just had to relocate the music load to inside the `if` statement.